# How to redirect user to same page from which it's logout due to login expire in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC5 identity for user login. Currently I using to logout an user if he/she inactive for specific period of time. Now I want to redirect him/her on the same page from which it logout; after the login once again. I am not sure whether it possible or not. Here is my **Login ActionResult**

```
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = new UserManager().IsValid(username, password);
        if (user!=null)
        {
            var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new[] { 
                    // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid,user.UserId.ToString()), 

                    // optionally add roles if any
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.OperationType),
                    //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),

                },
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(ident);
            // Set current principal
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

            UserManager userManager=new UserManager();
            userManager.GetUserMenu();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home"); // auth succeed 
        }
        // invalid username or password
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
        return View();
    }
```

And my **Startup Class**  class where I set mechanism for logout after a time period and all other,

```
   public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        { 
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,               
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")               ,
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                {
                    context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                    context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1); //for test purpose
                }
            },
            ReturnUrlParameter = ""    

        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
}
}
```

**My question is:** Is it possible if someone get logout for say `home/test` with `/Account/Login?=%2Fhome%2Ftest` as returnurl and then login once again, could it redirect him/her to `home/test` rather than `home/index`? If yes, then how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged out and redirected past that point you no longer have any reference to the previous url. When you hit your logout method though you have access to that. Store that in a cookie, check if it exists in your login method, and if it does expire the cookie and send them to the stored route.